# Tradução da mensagem de marcação de usuário em comentário

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização, comentários

Tentei marcar dois usuários num comentário e apareceu a mensagem:

> Só pode ser adicionado mais um @user; o proprietário da publicação sempre será notificado

Não seria o correto o trecho abaixo, sem o "mais"?

> Só pode ser adicionado um @user; o proprietário da publicação sempre será notificado

Comment: Me incomodou mais o *proprietário* do que esse *mais* que poderia sim ser retirado. Acho que o *autor* seria uma melhor tradução.

Answer (score 2):

Eu sugiro:

> Só pode ser adicionado um @usuario além do autor; o autor do post será sempre notificado.

Comment: Não resolve a incorreção da frase; melhor tirar o "além do autor".

Comment: "Só pode ser adicionado um @usuario; o autor da publicação será sempre notificado." parece bem razoável.

Comment: Eu trocaria "publicação" por "post". Fora isso, concordo.

Comment: Tem razão @Gabe, *post* fica melhor mesmo. Não vale a pena traduzir 100% dos termos

Comment: Eu tenho tentado usar sempre o português mas realmente tem horas que dá uma vontade de escrever *post* no lugar de postagem ou publicação.

Comment: @bigown Eu não acho que a gente deve se abster completamente de usar termos em inglês, principalmente considerando o assunto do site. Coisas como "login", "cookie", "browser" vão ser necessárias e neologismos tipo "deletar" ou "clicar" também. Acho que "post" é comum o suficiente no Brasil pra que não haja nenhum tipo de problema em usá-lo.

Comment: @Gabe Não sei porque as pessoas acham que deletar é neologismo, tem no dicionário e é de origem latina. Clicar já incorporou na língua. Tem termos como os que você citou não tem tradução mesmo, ninguém chama *e-mail* de correio eletrônico. Mas tem algumas palavras que tem tradução boa e ninguém usa e acaba ficando esquisito também, é o caso de *post*, só para dar 1 exemplo. Mas concordo que fica mais fácil se mais liberal se não exagerar. Acho ruim ficar inventando palavras que nem são inglês e nem português, que é o neologismo.

Comment: @bigown Ser de origem latina e ser uma palavra da língua portuguesa são duas coisas bem diferentes. Mas aqui não é o Etimologia Overflow, então a discussão foge ao ponto. O ponto é que não acredito que deva haver uma restrição obrigatória ao uso de termos estrangeiros, principalmente se forem comuns.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Estive a ler as sugestões já presentes bem como todos os comentários. Vejo muitas ideias apresentadas e poucas respostas na pergunta (na verdade, existe uma à data em que estou a escrever a minha).</sup>

A minha sugestão para alteração do texto atualmente em uso:

> Só pode adicionar um @user, o autor da publicação é sempre notificado.

[image: Captura de Tela]

**Nota:**
Optei por "publicação" pois de forma geral é o verbo em uso como pode ser visto no botão "Publique sua resposta" ou "Publicar sua pergunta".