# Por que não é permitido notificar mais de um usuário ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: suporte, comentários

#### Relacionado

[Tradução da mensagem de marcação de usuário em comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/75/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-mensagem-de-marca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-usu%C3%A1rio-em-coment%C3%A1rio)

#### Situação

Eu estava tentando notificar [dois usuário ao mesmo tempo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97376/javascript-codigo-apos-o-return), o @PauloHDSousa e o @rray, pois ambos solicitaram alteração no post, após editar gostaria de notificá-los.

#### Dúvida

Por que não é permitido notificar mais de um usuário ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Não sei o porquê mas só é permitido um por comentário. Deve ser uma medida anti-spam.

Comment: Relacionado: [Allow more than one @name notification per comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45273/229289) (É uma solicitação de novo recurso com status declinado, em Inglês)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment#comment219641_45296

Comment: @bfavaretto Ou seja, porque o Jeff não quis e ponto final, e dane-se se todo mundo discorda e deu fortes argumentos e explicações para embasar a discordância. Uma decisão baseada em uma falácia de *slippery slope* e totalmente ineficaz, uma vez que é facilmente contornada ao criar-se múltiplos comentários.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Concordo plenamente. Quem sabe estão dispostos a rever isso, agora que o Jeff não está mais.

Comment: Aliás, a justificativa para só mostrar os "split votes" pra quem tem 1000+ rep é parecida (mas disfarçada de problema de performance).

Comment: off: @bfavaretto Também podíamos tentar o suPT novamente **:P**